# Find which field will limit the result to zero records

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any standard way to find which clause has limited the result to zero record?

For example i have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb` WHERE `room` > 2 AND `keywords` LIKE 'Apartment'
```

If this query do not return any record, How i can find which field has limited the result to zero record.

When you try to search some thing, if there is no result, Some search engine show you a messeage like this:

> Try to search without **keywords**

Or if you are using `MATCH(city) AGAINST('tegas')` It show you:

> Are you meaning **texas**

Comment: What if it's only the combination of the two criteria that's resulted in no records?

Comment: The only way is to run a query with only one condition.

Comment: @dystroy And what about the `Did you mean?` ?

Comment: you could use a case and show a flag for condition, yo see if it has any result, but it will be complicated in complex querys

Comment: @hamidreza66 when you'll have the manpower that google has, you'll also know how to implement the `did you mean?` feature ;)

Answer (score 3):

During the query execution, all criteria is evaluated.  In order to determine if one specific item caused the query to return zero records, then you must run a separate statement for each criteria scenario.

I would suggest starting with all possible criteria, and then working back based off of the importance of the remaining items.  This way you are limiting the processing in the most effective manner.

Comment: And what about `Did you mean` message?

Comment: Use a combination of wildcard 'or' statements to check if the provided value matches any part of a valid record.